# Windows Python 2.7 wxwidgets and 'gizmos'

Tags: python, pip, wxwidgets

Can anyone give me precise instructions on how to access the wx 'gizmos' module?

```
import wx.gizmos
ImportError: No module named gizmos
```

The code in question has this:

```
import wx
import string
import wx.gizmos
from wx.lib.mixins import treemixin
import Descriptor
```

'pip list' reports

```
wxPython-Phoenix (3.0.3.dev1830+0b5f910)
```

Do I have the right package installed? I should add that these files are present:

```
\python27\Lib\wxpython\wx-3.0-msw\wx\gizmos.py
\python27\Lib\wxpython\wx-3.0-msw\wx\_gizmos.pyd
```

[edit] For clarification, this seems to be OK so I'm reasonably sure the WX module is installed correctly.

```
import wx
import copy
# had to add .agw to get this to load
import wx.lib.agw.customtreectrl as CT
import DescriptorDetailsPanel
```

TAIA

Comment: Are you sure that `wx` is the package in that location?

Comment: Hi Igancio, Yes. See my edit.

Comment: That doesn't answer what I asked. You may have more than one.

Comment: OK, 'pip list' shows only 1 wx package. How else can I test your hypothesis?

Comment: `import wx ; print wx.__file__`

Comment: => r:\apps\python27\lib\site-packages\wx\__init__.pyc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94711/discussion-between-g-forty-and-ignacio-vazquez-abrams).

Answer (score 0):

Congrats, you have two installs of wx. You can use `pkg_resources` to get the one you want. Put the following at the top of the script:

```
__requires__ = ["wx >= 3.0"]
import pkg_resources
```

This will tell `pkg_resources` to set things up so that a version of `wx` of at least 3.0 will be available if you import `wx` rather than the default 2.x.

Comment: File "r:\apps\python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 846,
 in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'wx>=3.0' distribution was not found and
 is required by the application

Comment: @GForty: Argh. Is there a "wx-*.egg-info" file on the system?

Comment: +10 for argh. No. Some egg-info for other packages but not wx.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to remove wxpython from pip install and reinstall wxpython from this site:

https://www.wxpython.org/download.php

It worked for me!